# send env variable from controller node to other nodes in ansible castle

Tags: ansible

I am trying to send an env variable from ansible controller node to the other nodes, now I only have the command `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts` and I can't change the playbook file, I can make another playbook file and set the env permanently but I don't want it since other processes can use this env variable.
I have access to the inventory file and ansible.cfg, is there any way to do it ??

I tried to send the env variable in ssh args but it's not working, I also tried something like this

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost

  environment:
    ENV_VAR: {{ env_var }}
  
  tasks:
  - name: Run the actual playbook
    command: {{ action_command }} # this is the ansible-playbook command 
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
```

but it's getting stuck at a point.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Since the [remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment) can only be set at task or play level in an `environment` stanza, what you are trying to achieve is actually not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It's not possible without setting the [environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) in a play, role, block, or task. (Credit @Zeitounator). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: all
  environment: "{{ env }}"
  ...
```

Details: On the controller, create a dictionary with the environment you want to "send" to the nodes. Put it into the *group_vars/all* if you can't modify the playbook

```yaml
  env: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {{ env_var|d('UENV') }}: {{ lookup('env', env_var|d('UENV'), default='UVAL') }}
    {% endfilter %}
```

If the variable *env_var* is not defined you get

```yaml
  env:
    UENV: UVAL
```

Use this dictionary to "send" the environment to the nodes. For example,

```yaml
    - command: "echo ${{ env_var|d('UENV') }}"
      environment: "{{ env }}"
      register: out
```

gives (if *env_var* is not defined)

```yaml
  out.stdout: UVAL
```

If you set `TEST_ENV=foo` in the controller environment and set the variable

```yaml
env_var: TEST_ENV
```

you get

```yaml
  out.stdout: foo
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── pb.ym
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test_11,test_13

  vars:

    env: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {{ env_var|d('UENV') }}: {{ lookup('env', env_var|d('UENV'), default='UVAL') }}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: env
      run_once: true

    - command: "echo ${{ env_var|d('UENV') }}"
      environment: "{{ env }}"
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
shell> TEST_ENV=foo ansible-playbook -e env_var=TEST_ENV pb.yml

PLAY [test_11,test_13] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  env:
    TEST_ENV: foo

TASK [command] *****************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  out.stdout: foo
ok: [test_13] => 
  out.stdout: foo

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: The problem here is that OP wants to send environment to a playbook he can't modify. As far as I'm aware, setting the remote environment can only be done at play or task level (hence in the non modifiable playbook). From my quick test, it does not work with `include_playbook` which was my first thought.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer.

Comment: can I pass it in ssh args? using -o SetEnv ?

Comment: What is preventing you from trying?